# How to test instance level Sequel::Model validations using minitest

Tags: ruby, validation, testing, minitest, sequel

Does anybody know of a straight forward method to test sequel model validations defined on instance level within the minitest framework?

**Background:**

I am developing a web application using sinatra and Sequel with an squlite database. The whole thing is a continuous development flow, since the web-app is part of a much larger development project, which is still under a lot of change. For that reason I am relying heavily on testing, since I have to "poke" around deeper in the data-structures quite regularly. As the testing framework I am using minitest with spec-files.

Now I run into a small problem. I want to test my Sequel::Model validations with minitest. I am using the :validation_helper plugin for Sequel::Model which quite nicely generates validations on instance level. My problem now is, that the only methods to test validations I found (e.g. [minitest-sequel](https://github.com/kematzy/minitest-sequel)) only work on class level validation, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just test the validations manually?:

```
model = Model.new
model.validate
model.errors[:column].must_equal ['some error message']
```

Comment: I'd recommend using "errors must include", not "errors must equal", for less fragile tests. But agree with the basic idea of just testing it manually like this.

Comment: That solves it pretty neatly. And it is quite obvious, but sometimes you just get stuck in a problem...